# Redirect in a Sitecore solution Noob

Tags: c#, regex, redirect, sitecore, sitecore7

Here What I am trying to do, my employer want to be able to be able do 301 redirect with regex expression with the alias in Sitecore so the way I am trying to implement this is like this!

a singleline text field
with a checkbox to tell sitecore it will be a regex expression I am a noob in .NET and Sitecore how can I implement this ? here a exemple http://postimg.org/image/lwr524hkn/

I need help the exemple of redirect I want handle is like this, this is a exemple of the redirect I want to do it could be product at the place of solution.

exemple.com/en/solution/platform-features to

exemple.com/en/platform-features

I base the code from http://www.cmssource.co.uk/blog/2011/December/modifying-sitecore-alias-to-append-custom-query-strings-via-301-redirect this is for query string I want to use regex expression.

```
    namespace helloworld.Website.SC.Common
{
    public class AliasResolver : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.AliasResolver
    {
        // Beginning of the Methods
        public new void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

            if (!Settings.AliasesActive)
            {
                Tracer.Warning("Aliases in AliasResolver are not active.");
            }
            else
            {
                Sitecore.Data.Database database = Context.Database;
                if (database == null)
                {
                    Tracer.Warning("There is no context in the AliasResolver.");
                }
                else
                { 


                    {
                        Profiler.StartOperation("Resolve virgin alias pipeline.");
                        Item item = ItemManager.GetItem(FileUtil.MakePath("/sitecore/system/aliases", args.LocalPath, '/'), Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.First, database, SecurityCheck.Disable);
                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            //Alias existis (now we have the alias item)
                            if (item.Fields["Regular Expressions"] != null)
                            {
                                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Fields["Regular Expressions"].Value) && !args.Url.QueryString.Contains("aproc"))
                                {
                                   var reg = new Regex(@"(?<Begin>([^/]*/){2})[^/]*/(?<End>.*)");
                                   var match = reg.Match(@"exemple.com/en/solution/platform-features");
                                   var result = match.Groups["Begin"].Value + match.Groups["End"].Value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Profiler.EndOperation();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("Had a problem in the VirginAliasResolver. Error: " + ex.Message, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ///<summary>
        ///  Once a match is found and we have a Sitecore Item, we can send the 301 response.
        ///</summary>
        private static void SendResponse(string redirectToUrl, HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            args.Context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            args.Context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            args.Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectToUrl);
            args.Context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I know they have module for this but my employer want it done that way and I am reaching for help since it's been a week I'm trying to add this feature

Comment: I really need help on this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want an alias with regex like example.com/en/solutions/* to be found and (mis)used for 301? I don't see why you would select an alias based on path and then perform an extra regex check.

Comment: I am only doing what my boss want It's my first time developing in .NET and sitecore and I don't know what to do, I just want the aliase to have a singleline text field where I could put this Regex string /([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$) with the aliases and be able to do 301 redirect from there and way that the string can know if it's regex or not that's why I tought of the checkbox.

Comment: I'm just trying to reach for help since I tried on my own and failed. I even got myself a course on pluralsight but this is way to advanced

Comment: And I'm trying to help you therefore I am asking what you're trying to achieve. Do you want all url's starting with example.com/en/solutions to redirect to an item in Sitecore? I can give you a push in the right direction but given the info its unclear to me what you are trying.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do
I want be able to add a regex redirection for every item exemple this page: exemple.com/en/solutions/platform-features  to exemple.com/en/platform-features

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand correctly, you do not want to select an Alias by path:

```
Item item = ItemManager.GetItem(FileUtil.MakePath("/sitecore/system/aliases", args.LocalPath, '/'), Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.First, database, SecurityCheck.Disable);
```

But rather find an Alias comparing a Regex field to the Url. I have not tested this, but it could be someting like:

```
var originalUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
var allAliases = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/system/aliases//*");
var foundAlias = allAliases.FirstOrDefault( alias =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(alias["Regular Expressions"]) &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), alias["Regular Expressions"]));
```

Then, if foundAlias != null, you can retrieve the url and redirect like you do in your private SendResponse function.

```
var linkField = (LinkField)foundAlias.Fields["linked item"];
var targetUrl = linkField.Url;
using (new SecurityDisabler()) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetUrl) && linkField.TargetItem != null)
       targetUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(linkField.TargetItem);
}

SendResponse(targetUrl, args);
```

Again, I have not tested this so don't shoot me if it needs some corrections, but this should help you get on your way.